# IIS Reverse proxy chunked response does not go through

Tags: iis, reverse-proxy, server-sent-events

I am using IIS as a revese proxy for some backend services. ARR or Helicon ISAPI_Rewrite. Everything works fine, except that chunked responses from the service do not go through IIS (the connection to the endpoint that happens to keep the connection open and sends some data back to the client in chunks) never answers. The service itself without a reverse proxy works well, i.e. client receives updates. This is similar to CouchDB /_changes endpoint with 'continous' mode.
In Chrome, the connection is marked as "pending".
I tried to disable all the caching on IIS, but no success.

The whole setup mimics sending SSE events, actually. Implementation of SSE also does not work obviously.

Is there any way to fix that?

Comment: Did you alerted any error messages? You can use F12 or Event Viewer to check if there are detailed error messages.

Comment: No, there are no errors. I am suspecting that the connection between IIS and the backend application server is not kept open. The connection between the client (a browser let's say) and the IIS is fine, but what is happening between the proxy and the backend is a problem. I tried ARR and the Helicon ISAPI_Rewrite, there is a clue I found in the Helicon documentation: https://www.helicontech.com/isapi_rewrite/doc/RewriteProxy.htm: "Force keep-alive connection between the client and IIS server (not between IIS and back-end). If not specified, connection will be closed upon each request."